Salesforce POST quick action with REST API
I'm new to salesforce, I wanted to know if it's possible to send a post form for quick actions to salesforce.
Description:
there is a detailed page on which there is a create record button, when clicked, a modal window opens where all the necessary data is entered, after saving, an entry is created in the linked table.
Of course, everything is fine from the salesforce interface, but I don't understand how to call this action through rest.
I tried the following method:
/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/Campaign/QuickActions/New Cart
Is there any approach to working with quick actions at all?
Thanks in advance)
